# Distribute value based on distance - pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas series as below which represents a distance from the point.

```
[53.14215611146749,
 68.38785810979309,
 73.39766970890767,
 62.55809054344587,
 61.65664511406602,
 67.30027137647377,
 53.18713806914155,
 44.731280834334726,
 56.775601188099564,
 48.70050608722388,
 52.058305375893326,
 43.86576801918336,
 40.7737929704101,
 48.14255989609582,
 66.1008274224399,
 64.14163441281926,
 74.19664861255285,
 39.2240226739306,
 43.19696483020877,
 56.19908015933838,
 52.75637095625348,
 72.94738557673514,
 68.43340406723989,
 55.3282335432387,
 14.063542002183079,
 65.42855719150613,
 64.57283331956563,
 55.7359195807484,
 46.47999444513133,
 67.90377608318023,
 45.20662678388409,
 60.89180227702483,
 55.498083875456516,
 66.27610947615794,
 22.845312320987933,
 55.68089486356418,
 37.17249970361574,
 31.996833503627055,
 8.004580252301615,
 57.701300278758396,
 55.68491218953833,
 49.69553182988371,
 62.857799532025695,
 64.4881255962942,
 56.52268246645304,
 53.70335480184844,
 47.68999060768484,
 70.19624652173587,
 46.06795699534889,
 43.10099872431838,
 39.554771098646285,
 39.35671580350949,
 63.702434120074344,
 63.97772732522319,
 55.721880827686036,
 40.45931808597496,
 54.21292609875884,
 16.675696857750737,
 41.39693209332469,
 54.254194394652124,
 20.35367440002031,
 59.334225047181775,
 54.27213837753601,
 71.06412120928913,
 32.77778238532229,
 44.525878012920465,
 21.633778938745873,
 62.82994949086467,
 53.74149464908078,
 43.55381629902706,
 62.06565329192727,
 60.84255535670013,
 69.61908591774456,
 62.42694740156783,
 24.305272369346792,
 53.67321288616061,
 41.51862527126106,
 53.06105426101688,
 52.29598013335814,
 56.56807611441198,
 54.44050075253376,
 69.0021067468377,
 51.62347224748836,
 52.22881959386345,
 46.864584528474325,
 47.012472881260116,
 51.646519289015345,
 45.619767144941775,
 8.519681182197928,
 68.36194018083505,
 24.231287660834653,
 54.903970823297854,
 38.8830383852113,
 60.93359558626832,
 60.20955222539125,
 49.42302250000802,
 44.393460251409024,
 41.81242566960246,
 56.712784485916885,
 19.378568603967558]
```

Now, I need to distribute a number (For example 15) across these 100 numbers.

If the distance is lower it should get a larger proportion of 15. If the distance is huge it should get lower proportion of 15.

i.e output of  14.063542002183079 should get a larger proportion (since it is closer), whereas 53.14215611146749 should get smaller (since it is far)

However, the sum of the 100 derived numbers should give me 15 (i.e. the value 15 is distributed based on distance).

What I have tried so far

I used softmax function to convert these distance numbers(list of 100) between 0 and 1.

Multipled each number in the list by 15. Now, the sum of the numbers in the list is 15.but the values are not distributed based on distance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
N = 15

dists   = 1 / (s - N).abs()
weights = dists / dists.sum()

result = weights * N
```

- find the distances as absolute difference to N but inverted so closer the better
- get weights as the normalized distances by their sum
- distribute N with weights

Comment: `dists   = (s - N).abs()` - what does s denote ? Each number in the list ?

Comment: `s` is the series you mentioned

Comment: `s = pd.Series([50, 20, 100])`

` N = 15`

output i get is `54.2, 20.6, 110.2` .

Comment: but, i want to give more weight to the nearest distance. 20 should have more weight. And the result series should add up to N (i.e. 15)

Comment: yeah sorry i didn't invert the distances. Edited the answer; now it's the closer the more weight. noting that `1 / d` is one way one of getting that inverse relationship.

Comment: resultant series will add up to "original_sum + N"

Comment: No. I want to distribute N.. So the resultant sum should add up to N

Comment: `weights * N` satisfies that both; sums up to `N`, and also bigger when value is near `N` and smaller otherwise.

Comment: i thought you wanted to add it back, sorry. i edited that part out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add all the distances up, then divide each distance by the sum of all distances. This should give you the percentage (value between 0 and 1) each value has in comparison to the sum. Then multiply by 15 and you're done.

EDIT:
I misunderstood you, here is a solution that distributes the values linearly.

```py
p_list = [20, 50, 100]
distribution_val = 15

# assuming the point that is the most distant gets the value 0
for i, p in enumerate(p_list):
    p_list[i] = p*-1 + max(p_list)

sum = sum(p_list)
for i, p in enumerate(p_list):
    val = p / sum
    val *= distribution_val
    p_list[i] = val

print(p_list) # [9.23, 5.77, 0] => sum = 15
```

If you want to give the most distant point also a value, just add `max(p_list) + min_points`

Comment: This wont work out as well. For example, lets take a simple series `pd.Series([50, 20, 100])`

Comment: sum is 170. hence the series becomes - (0.29, 0.11, 0.58). if we multiply by 15, the second element will get less weightage

Comment: ooh, its inverted, sorry

Comment: I added a working solution for the problem now @srinath. This should distribute the values linearly depending on their distance.